# Java: How to show Jar file path for "method undefined" exceptions?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the cause of a "The method ... is undefined for the type ..." exception, which I think is due to a classpath issue, picking up an older version of the class. How do can I dump out the path to the JAR from which the class is being loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your java with `-verbose:class` parameter. This will print when and where classes are loaded into the VM.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Foo.class.getResource("Foo.class"));
```

or

```
System.out.println(Foo.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
  .getLocation());
```